# Word 2016 - Check spelling without checking grammar

Tags: spell-check, microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-word-2016, review, proofing

In Word 2016, how do I check spelling without checking grammar?

I am virtually never interested in checking the grammar of my documents. When I look in the Review pane, I only find the choice *Spelling & Grammar* – no alternative to check spelling only.

[image: Screenshot from the »ribbon« in Word]

I have tried to to disable the option *Check grammar with spelling* but that doesn’t help.

Answer (score 6):

You need to go to `File -> Options -> Proofing -> When correcting spelling and grammar in Word` and uncheck `Mark grammar errors as you type` and `Check grammar with spelling`. You also should click `Settings...` from `Writing Style` and uncheck everything in the box you do not want to see corrected.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help. I have unchecked *Mark grammar errors as you type* and *Check grammar with spelling*, but that doesn't seem to affect the behaviour of the *Spelling & Grammar* button (see screenshot above).

Comment: @CarlWinbäck That is odd, it works fine on my system (Win 10). Perhaps try resetting all of the Proofing options to default, then try setting them back? If that doesn't help, the only other solution I can think of is reinstalling Word 2016.